# Getting error when i want to start the App (Google Play service keeps stopping)

Tags: java, android, sdk, emulation

every time i want to start the app in the Android Studio, i keep getting this error! curious tho, i ended yesterday evening the programming session, everything was fine, and now i wanted to continue, and now it stucks! [The Error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n44e.png)

and when i open the "Open logcat panel for emulator Pixel 4 API UpsideDownCakePrivacySandbox"

it shows me a very long red text in the middle of the log !

2024-01-06 19:33:19.921 15023-15023 AndroidRuntime          com.example.gettingstartedapp        E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.gettingstartedapp, PID: 15023
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gettingstartedapp/com.example.gettingstartedapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gettingstartedapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~VwMVlDQ_9CTo8egotcsaAA==/com.example.gettingstartedapp-Y1wQmv2sCLxcKNacn5RW6A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~VwMVlDQ_9CTo8egotcsaAA==/com.example.gettingstartedapp-Y1wQmv2sCLxcKNacn5RW6A==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.gettingstartedapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~VwMVlDQ_9CTo8egotcsaAA==/com.example.gettingstartedapp-Y1wQmv2sCLxcKNacn5RW6A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~VwMVlDQ_9CTo8egotcsaAA==/com.example.gettingstartedapp-Y1wQmv2sCLxcKNacn5RW6A==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3676)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

hope someone can help me, thx!

i tried to reinstall android studio, restart project

Comment: can you post your app level gradle file?

Comment: Where can i find that? Sorry im new to Android studio

Comment: when i go inside the project folder under app/gradle.build there is not a file, there a 4 more containers with more containers

Comment: the file should be build.gradle. Please have a look at answer. You need to enable multidex

Comment: I did enable, i Had a kotlin build.gradle.sdk i enabled but after that i got another error Like those which i wrote in the comments under this comment where you told me how to activate

Comment: I created a new File and the error was gone, and the App was starting on the Emulator, but in the the message was still there with " keeps closing "

Comment: Please post the contents of your build.gradle file

Comment: how can i post it ? i mean i cant post a screenshot in the comments

Comment: you can edit ur question and post the contents of your gradle file

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter the issue with `dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass`, it typically means that the Android runtime (Dalvik or ART) is unable to find the specified class during runtime. Try these steps to troubleshoot and resolve this issue

1. Make sure the `MainActivity` is in the correct package directory within your Android project.
2. It is possible that your Gradle file is loading a substantial number of third-party libraries, causing your DEX limit to be reached. You may consider increasing your DEX size. You can refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/build/multidex) for guidance

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: i did that but now i got an fail in the build output -> build: JavaKotlin: failed and a huge error list i would like to post a screenshot but i dont know where i can do this.

Comment: :App:mergeDebugResource, App:packageDebugResource,  app:create:DebugCompatibleScreenManifest, app:mergeDebug.Java.Resource, app:mergeExtDexDebug, app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersion (with inside 15 more Errors), and Cannot Snapshot